# How to install netCDF4 and extract netCDF data file in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf, data-extraction

I want to extract a netCDF data file using Python. I installed Numpy, netCDF4-Python and h5py for this purpose. But, it gives an error message

> ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

What's wrong with that? Or, is there any easier way to extract netCDF files in python?

Comment: Does a plain `import numpy` work?  How about `import numpy.core.multiarray`?  Do you have `scipy`?  That has a `netcdf` reader that does not require external (nonpython) netcdf code.

Comment: Thanky you, @hpaulj ..actually I had an older version of numpy...however, I have fixed it.